# like button revert after click on mobile web?

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-like

I make a mobile web with a like button to simulate a like gate-way. 
When user click on it,  it triggered edge_create event, the like button turn grey, but then it revert immediately and go to the fan page.
But if the user press on the like button long enough, the like action is triggered correctly.

I cannot figure out what is the reason and how to fix it...any one has the same issue?